# Excel: bordering specific cells with non-numeric text

Tags: excel, border, vba

I'm making a chart of guitar chords for various songs, and I border each cell that contains chords, each cell representing one bar of the song. However, I need three conditions to be met in how the borders apply.

1. I only want cells to be bordered if they contain chords and to remain unbordered if they're empty, otherwise the printed sheet looks very messy. See my pic at the bottom if I didn't explain that well.
2. Also, some cells have the number 1 or the number 2 (to denote song parts), which I DON'T want bordered (See the cell denoted by the green arrow in my pic).
3. On top of that, and I don't know if this is possible, I want cells to be bordered even if they have overflow text running into them, but no actual text attributed to the cell itself. When I highlight two cells, one with text overflowing into the next, and hit "all borders," excel automatically leaves the side of the cell that has text running through it without a border, and only borders the perimeter. I show an example of this at the red arrow in my pic.

So, my question is, is there a formula that I can use to conditionally format my whole chord chart all at once that will satisfy all three conditions?

The reason I want the formatting to be conditional (other than that its just easier) is to be able to automatically alphabetize and add songs, and have all that careful formatting go along with them (when I did the border formatting manually, and alphabetized my songs, the formatting stayed right where it had been :/ )

**Example Picture**

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific range of cells that you are working with? A macro that has to check every cell in a sheet will run considerably slower.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any VBA for this, as Excel's inbuilt Conditional Formatting will do the job nicely.

1) Select all the cells (click the blank grey corner to the top-left of A1).

2) On the Home tab, click Conditional Formatting -> New Rule

3) Click "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".

4) In the formula bar, enter:

```
=AND(NOT(A1=""),NOT(ISNUMBER(A1)))
```

5) In the below box, click the "Format..." button to open up the cell formatting dialogue box. From there, you can click the "Border" tab and then "Outline".

6) Click OK and OK.

This simply tells the sheet to apply the border format to any cell which is not empty, AND is not a number.

Comment: I concur. It would also be much faster than anything VBA could do.

Comment: Thanks. Bobbular, if you're happy with this answer, please click the tick and turn it green to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, took me a while to find but this update worked for me: 
Issues affecting Excel features and add-ins

**Dark borders around rows and cells appear when entering text in Excel 2016 after Sept 12, 2017 update (KB4011050) [FIXED]**

Last updated: Sep 14, 2017

ISSUE

After installing the September 12, 2017 update for Excel 2016 (KB4011050), dark borders may appear around rows or cells in Excel spreadsheets when you enter text.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Fixes-or-workarounds-for-recent-issues-in-Excel-for-Windows-49d932ce-0240-49cf-94df-1587d9d97093